# What actually happens when Session.Abandon() is called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm curious what happens when Session.Abandon() is called on a MVC Application. I'm calling this method when a user in my Application fails the authentication.

```
public ActionResult Authentication(string message = "")
{
    Session.Abandon();
    return View(new ErrorMessage { message = message});
}
```

Is it good practice in this scenario?

Should I be calling this on all Error Redirects?

When else should I be calling Session.Abandon() in a life-cycle of an MVC Application?

Comment: You do not need to call `Session.Abandon()` explicitly, unless you use SessionState to track authenticated user *which is not a good practice*. What is your concern?

Comment: I suppose I am not using SessionState at all, so I may not need to use the line Session.Abandon(). My concern is whether I'm missing something here and should be using it somewhere else possibly.

Comment: Well, only you can answer this question. What are you storing in the session? Is there anything worth destroying and what would be the requirement for you to do so? A session is always created the first time a user hits the server. It means nothing unless you actually store something in it. If the user is failing authentication, I would imagine nothing relevant would be stored there anyways.

Comment: I believe my answer would be not to wait my time destroying the session. I am not storing any information here and do not need to do anything special with it at application end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx):

> The Abandon method destroys all the objects stored in a Session object and releases their resources. If you do not call the Abandon method explicitly, the server destroys these objects when the session times out